# Docker remote volume and remote machine performance

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-volume

I am planning a setup where, the docker containers are using remote volume - volume that have ssh-ed to another machine and it is reading all the time.

Lets say we have 5 containers using that remote volume. In my understanding, the docker is ssh-ed to the remote machine and constantly reading on certain directory (with about 100 files, not more than few MB).

Presumably that constant reading will put some load to the remote machine. Will that load be significant or it can be negligible? There is php-fpm and Apache2 on the remote machine, will the constant reading slow down that web server? Also, how often the volume is refreshing the files?

Sincerely.

Comment: You can mount remote machine's location to your first machine as a mount point. I don't think the remote's machine processes (php-fpm or Apache2) will get effected, only latency would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after some testing:

1. I have created a remote volume with vieux/sshfs driver.
2. Created an ubuntu container with the volume mounted under certain folder.
3. Then tail a txt file from the container itself.
4. Write to that txt file form the remote machine (the one that contains the physical folder).

I have found out, if we write to the file continuously (like echo "whatever" >> thefile.txt). The changes appear all at once after few seconds, not one by one as they have been introduced. Also, if I print or list the files in the mounted directory, the response is instant. This makes me thing, that Docker is making local copy of the folder ssh-ed in the volume and refreshes it every 5 sec or so. Basically negligible load after the folder is copied once.

Also, when trying to write from the container to the mounted folder, the changes on the file are reflected almost instantly (considering any latency). Which makes me think that the daemon is propagating the write changes instantly.

In conclusion - reading a remote folder, puts negligible load to the remote machine. The plan is to use such setup in production environment, so we don't have to pull changes on two different places (prod server and machine which is sharing (local) volume between containers).

If there is anyone who can confirm my findings, that would be great.

Sincerely